# cursor tracking using matplotlib and twinx

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to track the coordinates of the mouse with respect to *data coordinates* on two axes simultaneously. I can track the mouse position with respect to one axis just fine. **The problem is:** when I add a second axis with `twinx()`, both `Cursors` report data coordinates with respect to the *second* axis only.

For example, my Cursors (`fern` and `muffy`) report the `y`-value is 7.93

```
Fern: (1597.63, 7.93)
Muffy: (1597.63, 7.93)
```

If I use:

```
    inv = ax.transData.inverted()
    x, y = inv.transform((event.x, event.y))
```

I get an IndexError.

So the question is: How can I modify the code to track the data coordinates with respect to both axes?

---

### [image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Cursor(object):
    def __init__(self, ax, name):
        self.ax = ax
        self.name = name
        plt.connect('motion_notify_event', self)

    def __call__(self, event):
        x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
        ax = self.ax
        # inv = ax.transData.inverted()
        # x, y = inv.transform((event.x, event.y))
        logger.debug('{n}: ({x:0.2f}, {y:0.2f})'.format(n=self.name,x=x,y=y))


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(message)s',)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.linspace(1000, 2000, 500)
y = 100*np.sin(20*np.pi*(x-1500)/2000.0)
fern = Cursor(ax, 'Fern')
ax.plot(x,y)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
z = x/200.0
muffy = Cursor(ax2, 'Muffy')
ax2.semilogy(x,z)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The commented out code you have also seems to work so I am confused what the problem is.

Comment: @tcaswell: I simplified my code too much. When I use `ax2.semilogy`, for some reason the commented-out code raises an IndexError.

Comment: I think this is a bug, if you get the inverted transform for the `transData` it does not behave properly outside of the call back and is raising errors from `transfroms.py`

Comment: I think I found a work-around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to the way that the call backs work, the event always returns in the top axes.  You just need a bit of logic to check which if the event happens in the axes we want:

```
class Cursor(object):
    def __init__(self, ax, x, y, name):
        self.ax = ax
        self.name = name
        plt.connect('motion_notify_event', self)

    def __call__(self, event):
        if event.inaxes is None:
            return
        ax = self.ax
        if ax != event.inaxes:
            inv = ax.transData.inverted()
            x, y = inv.transform(np.array((event.x, event.y)).reshape(1, 2)).ravel()
        elif ax == event.inaxes:
            x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
        else:
            return
        logger.debug('{n}: ({x:0.2f}, {y:0.2f})'.format(n=self.name,x=x,y=y))
```

This might be a subtle bug down in the transform stack (or this is the correct usage and it was by luck it worked with tuples before), but at any rate, this will make it work.  The issue is that the code at line 1996 in `transform.py` expects to get a 2D `ndarray` back, but the identity transform just returns the tuple that get handed into it, which is what generates the errors.

Comment: @unutbu yes, but one could argue there is no point in re-doing the display -> data conversion that has already been done to populate `xdata` and `ydata` attributes

Comment: This has been really helpful. Thanks so much.

Comment: someone did and I would like to know why (guessed you as I left this link on a question you commented on).  No worries, sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 2):

You can track both axis coordinates with one cursor (or event handler) this way:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Cursor(object):
    def __init__(self):
        plt.connect('motion_notify_event', self)

    def __call__(self, event):
        if event.inaxes is None:
            return
        x, y1 = ax1.transData.inverted().transform((event.x,event.y))
        x, y2 = ax2.transData.inverted().transform((event.x,event.y))
        logger.debug('(x,y1,y2)=({x:0.2f}, {y1:0.2f}, {y2:0.2f})'.format(x=x,y1=y1,y2=y2))

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(message)s',)
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

x = np.linspace(1000, 2000, 500)
y = 100*np.sin(20*np.pi*(x-1500)/2000.0)
fern = Cursor()
ax1.plot(x,y)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
z = x/200.0
ax2.plot(x,z)
plt.show()
```

(I got "too many indices" when I used `ax2.semilogy(x,z)` like the OP, but didn't work through that problem.)

The `ax1.transData.inverted().transform((event.x,event.y))` code performs a transform from display to data coordinates on the specified axis and can be used with either axis at will.

Comment: Thanks @CarpeCimex. The problem is, I use the `Cursor` in situations where there is only one axes as well as with twinx axes. So I don't want Cursor to assume there is always two axes, `ax1` and `ax2`.

Comment: I see. You can put `x, y = ax.transData.inverted().transform((event.x,event.y))` in your original `__call__` function in place of the commented-out code and do just that, though.  (There is still the "too many indices" problem when using `ax2.semilog()` though, but that's a separate problem.)

Comment: Oh... I see now, this question does not make a whole to sense any more since the bug in matplotlib has now been fixed.

Comment: @CarpeCimex Thank you for your answer. I have a simpler situation (always `ax` and `ax.twinx()` overlapped) and this helped a lot!