# How to make a twin y-axis by only taking the maximum value of the line indicated from 0 to 1

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I know how to plot twin y-axis but for my problem, I need to make a twin y-axis in percentages (like 0.1 = 10% to 1 = 100%) and here the maximum value or the end point of the line graph should be matched with '1' i.e.100%. 
For example: `x = 1,3,6,8` & `y=2,7,9,17` now if we plot this we know the highest point is (8,17) then w.r.t. this point(8,17) I need to show on the twin y-axis as '1' the twin y-axis can be a dummy axis as it is just needed as a reference axis to compare the graph.

I tried using normalization method but the original plot is getting disturbed and also the y-axis points are displayed according to new twin axis not with the original y-axis values.

For reference, this is the current output:

[image]

Below is my code which I tried.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#below x and y points can be changed according to the user
y = np.array([0, 38, 71, 99, 123, 205])
x = np.array([0, 0.37, 0.74, 1.11, 1.48, 1.85])

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(x, y,'b--')
yrep = y-min(y[:])
yrep = yrep/max(yrep[:])
print (yrep,"yrep")
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(x, yrep, alpha=0)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Setting `ax1.set_ylim(y.min(), y.max())` and `ax2.set_ylim(0, 1)` should be sufficient in your specific example?

Comment: Yes this is working as I need but the only problem is when I place my cursor on the line the y-coordinate values are showing in the range 0 to 1 not as per the original y-axis values ( 0, 38, 71, 99, 123, 205).

Comment: This doesn't sound like something which is very easy to fix (see e.g. this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672530/cursor-tracking-using-matplotlib-and-twinx/16672970#16672970)

Comment: Thanks for the link but is it possible to make dummy twin axis beacuse I need to do other plottings w.r.t. original y-axis values. Now the problem is if I am trying to plot points on the line graph by taking y-axis values but it is taking twin y-axis values 0 to 1.

Comment: I don't understand your last question/point. You can plot on the original (left) axis using e.g. `ax1.plot(..)`?

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say why when I keep the cursor on the graph it is showing y-coordinates values from the twin axis but not the original y-axis. In the link you mentioned it is showing all 3 axes and it is bit complicated as I don't need to display the all coordinates; I should only able to see the x and original y coordinates in the bottom right side of the graph.

Comment: Based on several questions here on SO, it seems that there is no easy solution to fix that.

Comment: The code from the question shows the coordinates of the first axes (ax1). See [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxbrA.png). So you would probably just want to update your matplotlib version.

Comment: What exactly you mean 'update your matplotlib version'. Do you mean I need to install new version of matplotlib.

Comment: Is it possible to make the ticks and gridlines aligned on both y-axis.
I'm looking for a general way to do that rather than doing manually. i.e. if I get any two datasets of yaxis and twin y-axis how do I set up the plot in a way that the gridlines coincides for two axis.